# Plot animation between source/destination IP addresses

Tags: animation

Can anyone share code with me that will plot and animate "attack lines or points" between a source IP address and destination IP address, or vice versa.  I'm trying to recreate the Norse dashboard here: http://www.norse-corp.com/technology_overview.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option would be to have a look at the soucecode of the map itself:

http://map.ipviking.com/

especially http://map.ipviking.com/ipviking.js

to see how you can do this with d3.js

The coordinates are sent through the websocket in following syntax:
    {"latitude":"32.06","longitude":"118.78","countrycode":"CN","country":"CN","city":"Nanjing","org":"Chinanet Jiangsu Province Network","latitude2":"25.04","longitude2":"121.53","countrycode2":"TW","country2":"TW","city2":"Taipei","type":"ipviking.honey","md5":"222.186.21.60","dport":"3128","svc":"3128","zerg":""}

Something like that you could realize if you contact an API like ip-api.com:

http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json